# Enabling Autocompletion for a Custom Command

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

I have the following lines in my vimrc:

```
command -nargs=1 Compare call Compare(<f-args>)
function Compare(file)
    execute "vnew " . a:file
    setlocal nomodifiable
    wincmd h
endfunction
```

It immutably opens a given file in a new window strictly for reference. This works perfectly for me (though I am open to suggestions to improve it).

What I'd like to add is the ability to <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocomplete files, like with other commands that take files like `:e` or `:vnew`. All that does right now is type `^I` (I have `nocompatible` set, so that's not an issue).

I've done some looking around, but I haven't found a way that would work with just <kbd>Tab</kbd>. `cmdline-completion`, `wildchar`, and `wildmode` don't seem to have the answer I'm looking for.

Is there a way to tell Vim that the command should expect a file or otherwise enable <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, see `:help -complete` and try

```
command -nargs=1 -complete=file Compare call Compare(<f-args>)
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, but I just couldn't find it. Thank you very much!